# INT field cannot be used in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, int

I am having this annoying problem with my query:

I have the table **tbl_profissao** with the fields 
**idtbl_profissao** (INT(11), A.I.,UNSIGNED, NOT NULL),
**cbo** (INT(6), UNSIGNED, ZERO FILL) and
**profissao** (VARCHAR(110)).

I split my query into two PHP pages - **profissao_busca.php** and **profissao_busca_input.php**, with the following codes:

For profissao_busca.php:

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
<body>
<h2>PESQUISA: PROFISSÃO (CBO) </h2>
<form id="form_profissao_busca" method="post" action="profissao_busca.php?go">
<p>Por favor, escreva o número CBO da profissão que quer encontrar:<br/><br/>
<input name="busca_cbo" type="text" id="busca_cbo" size="11" maxlength="11" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="PROCURAR" /></p>
</form>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){
  if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['busca_cbo'])){
  $name=$_POST['busca_cbo'];

    $db=mysql_connect  ("localhost", "root",  "root") or die ('Não foi possível conectar-se ao Banco de Dados (erro No.): ' . mysql_error());
    $mydb=mysql_select_db("grcc_db_pr");
    $sql="SELECT idtbl_profissao, cbo, profissao FROM tbl_profissao WHERE profissao LIKE '%$name%' OR idtbl_profissao LIKE '%$name%' OR cbo LIKE '%$name%'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $Pessoa=$row['cbo'];
        $ident=$row['idtbl_profissao'];
        $prof=$row['profissao'];
  echo "<ul>\n";
  echo "<li> CBO requisitado: " . $Pessoa . "</li><li> Identificador: ". $ident . "</li><li>Ocupação:" . $prof . "</li><li>
  <form id=\"form_profissao_busca\" method=\"post\" action=\"profissao_busca_input.php?go\">
  <input name=\"button\" type=\"submit\" value=\"BUSCAR ESTE CBO\" />
  <input name=\"busca_cbo\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"". $ident. "\" /></form></li>\n";
  echo "</ul>";
  }
  }
  else{
  echo  "<p>Este número não existe no Banco de Dados</p>";
  }
  }
  }
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

And for profissao_busca_input.php:

```
<?php include "header.php";
$nome_proc = $_POST['busca_cbo'];
        // ================== Dados pessoais e documentos
$listagem =  "SELECT idtbl_profissao, cbo, profissao FROM tbl_profissao WHERE profissao LIKE '%$name%' OR idtbl_profissao LIKE '%$name%' OR cbo LIKE '%$name%'";
$resultado = mysql_query($listagem);
$listagem = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);

print "<ul><li> CBO requisitado:  $listagem[1] </li><li> Identificador: $listagem[0] </li><li>Ocupação: $listagem[2] </li></ul>";
```

Having a small sample of the table as:

idtbl_profissao,cbo,profissao

```
1,'010205','Oficial da aeronáutica'
2,'010210','Oficial do exército'
3,'010210','X5020'
4,'010215','Oficial da marinha'
5,'010215','X6020'
6,'010215','X6030'
```

The problem is that when I put any value belonging to "cbo" column the result is "Este número não existe no Banco de Dados" (meaning the value does not exist in the Database). Whenever I put either a word or alphanumeric value from column "profissao" it works fine.

Now I don't know what is going on, or if I missed something because "cbo" is in INT format.

Anyway, thank you in advance for your attention.

Nicole

Comment: Use prepared statements and execute the variables into the query (or bindparameter). Also, don't use the mysql syntax, It's deprecated. I recommend using PDO, you can google it, or find a various of examples on Stackoverflow (Posted a lot on my profile aswell).

Comment: Can you just cut this down for us and explain the problem query which is not returning the expected results?

Comment: i tried to replicate your problem and it's working on fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8df9f/2

Comment: Mike, I tried to explain the problem above; the query from the page profissao_busca.php returns nothing if I input anything from field "cbo". Just that.

Comment: J W, I made the query on fiddle as:

SELECT idtbl_profissao, cbo, profissao 
FROM TableName 
WHERE cbo LIKE '1010205'

and nothing came out. This is what I was talking about, I don't know if I messed up the explanation in the first place, but the problem relies on the "cbo" columnm always.

Comment: Jonast92, I never heard of this PDO.. sorry.. I'm a novice...(noob, if you prefer)

Comment: @JW, I made the query on fiddle as:

SELECT idtbl_profissao, cbo, profissao 
FROM TableName 
WHERE cbo LIKE '1010205'

and nothing came out. This is what I was talking about, I don't know if I messed up the explanation in the first place, but the problem relies on the "cbo" columnm always.

Anyway, I still don't get why LIKE '%$name%' on the code above would not work. Thanks for trying, but the rest of the code from my pages remains the same - not working at all.

It's strange that in sqlfiddle LIKE '%10205%' returns fine, and LIKE '%010205%' does not; can you explain why?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that there is a second problem with the code: Whenever I input any string from column 'cbo' and have a return, after pressing the button to have the result processed by the page profissao_busca_input.php the result is always the first entry in the database table. What is annoying is that I have this exact same structure of query for another pair of tables and it runs fine. The difference in the case here is that I need to fetch results from either two columns instead of only one.